# How to return distance and all fields using elasticsearch and spring-boot (springframework.data.elasticsearch)

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I found a way to get my data using elasticsearch query. But my current problem is to translate it in spring boot query.

My query is the following:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "my_field": "my_value"
              }
            },
            "boost": 10
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "my_field": "my_value"
              }
            },
            "boost": 8
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "my_array_field": [
              "first_value",
              "second_value"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "10km",
            "location": {
              "lat": 40,
              "lon": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "script": "doc['location'].arcDistance(40, 2) / 1000"
    }
  },
  "_source": true,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": "desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

All documents stored in the index have a fields `location`, with a type defined as a `geo_point`

My question is:

How to translate the `script_fields`, which is returning me the distance, using spring-boot.

My current code is:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(boolQueryBuilder)
                .withPageable(PageRequest.of(page, size))
                .build();

elasticsearchOperations.search(nativeSearchQuery, MyIndexedDocument.class);
```

I tried to use ScriptField from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/ScriptField.html) and saw an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/ff381c63b6d7633a7a17b3d8a63db36661763afe/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplateTests.java#L798) but didn't find any solution for now.

1. How should I use it?
2. If think, after finding how to return distance, I will have to precise to my query that I want all the `_source` field in return. Is it possible to precise it using `NativeSearchQuery` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer as a workaround**

I let the question without any validated answer in case of somebody has a better answer.

In case it's a question which is relevant for somebody, I finally choose to deal the distance return by using geo distance sort.

*The query is something like this:*

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "my_field": "my_value"
              }
            },
            "boost": 10
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "my_field": "my_value"
              }
            },
            "boost": 8
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "my_array_field": [
              "first_value",
              "second_value"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "10km",
            "location": {
              "lat": 40,
              "lon": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
    "sort" : [
        { "_score": "desc"},{
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
                      "lat": 40,
                      "lon": 2
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km",
        "mode": "min",
        "distance_type": "arc",
        "ignore_unmapped": true
      }
    }
   ]
}
```

So I can get my distance in return, but not as a field of *content*, but as a value in *sortvalues*

*Using spring data elasticsearch:*

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
ScoreSortBuilder scoreSortBuilder = new ScoreSortBuilder();
GeoDistanceSortBuilder geoDistanceSortBuilder = new GeoDistanceSortBuilder("location", Double.parseDouble(location.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(location.getLongitude()));
geoDistanceSortBuilder.unit(DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS);
geoDistanceSortBuilder.ignoreUnmapped(true);
geoDistanceSortBuilder.sortMode(SortMode.MIN);
geoDistanceSortBuilder.order(SortOrder.ASC);

NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(boolQueryBuilder)
                .withPageable(PageRequest.of(page, size))
                .withSort(scoreSortBuilder)
                .withSort(geoDistanceSortBuilder)
                .build();

elasticsearchOperations.search(nativeSearchQuery, MyIndexedDocument.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the annotation @ScriptedField